# Flash Pro, debugging trough usb with Motorola Moto g

Tags: android, flash-cs5, usb-debugging

That's about it, I'm trying to get the debug to USB option on Flash CS5 with my new Moto g but I can't find the way to get it. I've allowed USB debugging on the phone. I´ve Motorola Device Manager installed (with the drivers) but if I uncheck the multimedia on the usb options of the phone Windows asks for drivers, there's no charge only option on my phone.

In the Android SDK I'am not able to launch the SDK Manager in order to download Android tools. I've used the CMD on the platform-tools folder and written adb/devices. I get a long list of options so I think it recognises the phone (on multimedia) but still doesn't appears on Flash.

Any clue how I could get this working? Thanks

Comment: if you run `adb.exe devices` does it say that the device is plugged?

Comment: If I run adb.exe it closes itself after a moment. Huh, I just used my cmd window and it has initialized daemon, it says the devide is attached but unauthorized.

Comment: ...and I didn´t notice the message on my phone. Now it is authorized but still not getting the option to debug by usb on flash.

Comment: I can´t find the way to install the driver when the device is not connectes neither as mass storage or camera, wich I guess is the problem. I've looked in the Motorola folders of the Device Manager, I've tried the Google USB driver but this didn´t worked. I foun an exe in the Motorola folders called ForwardDaemon.exe, but it doesn't seem to help. Gonna try reinstalling Motorola Device Manager eith the device connected without the mass storage option. Gracias Sergi.

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening.. Recently I purchased Nexus5 and all I had to do was the following: plug device, install drivers (google adb nexus drivers, from documentation), accept the popup shown in my device, and that was it

Comment: I can´t find the way to install the drivers when the phone is not in mass storage mode, gonna look in the Motorola forums or something. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I also got Motorola G recently. Make sure that **USB debug** is enabled, and that you have Developer options in Settings. You have to tap about 5 times on device firmware version in the About phone section to enable Developers options.

Answer (score 0):

As mentione in the above post, make sure USB debug is enabled and if the command prompt adb devices command shows "Unauthorized" , make sure you have OKed the dialog that pops up on the phone saying :"Your computer RSA fingerprint ... Are you sure you want to enable debug".

Once you grant you will see your device as connected.